# p2wpkh spending problem

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-cli, p2wpkh

I use unsynced bitcoin core wallet because data is too costly and I do not trust anything other than bitcoin core, people told me to do so.

Playing around I originated this transaction id: e11bdbf2ecaa4309ba7664fe53876d04c47b2faf6aa428c7fd7c1bd574c0c85e
I want to spend them to another address.
So I constructed a new transaction and wanted to sign it, I believe I have to redeem a P2wpkh script to unlock the funds :

```
signrawtransactionwithkey "02000000015ec8c074d51b7cfdc728a46aaf2f7bc4046d8753fe6476ba0943aaecf2db1be10000000000ffffffff01e485010000000000160014a6d3b75abe310aaa1dbcfe6a78d1d96307cd11c400000000" '''["Myprivatekey"]''' '''[{"txid": "e11bdbf2ecaa4309ba7664fe53876d04c47b2faf6aa428c7fd7c1bd574c0c85e","vout": 0,"scriptPubKey": "001491a4d1774ba4d8d19c2a880ab42460589ed6c98f", "amount": 0.00099812}]'''
```

But bitcoin core tells me that there is witness program hash mismatch.
Can someone please help me.
Cordially

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I lost a full day on it. But the solution was annoyingly simple, the hash is invalid, just provide the proper private key. I just messed up in my mind, I was pursuaded my arguments were correct.